# Is it possible to use pure functionality of sqlite-net-pcl and Akavache using it in same project?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, .net-standard, akavache

In `Akavache` docs said that it's *powered* by `SQLite`.
And from what I heard Akavache is quite nice tool for the key-value storage and sometimes you just don't want to store some cached data into SQL.

Also, usually in mobile apps you also require some data stored in SQL-manner.

In that case it requires two db approaches to be used through the app: SQL and Non-SQL. So, as long as Akavache is still based on SQLite, **is there any way to use both**: SQLite and Akavache, which uses the sam SQLite (files)?

This is referred in context of Xamarin .NET Standard projects.

Any hints?

Comment: There is no reason you can't.  Akavache will create its own backend db file.

Comment: But apparently that's rather not possible if they use the same file? It's not like I would definitely need that, but just to understand the way it works...

Comment: Well, no, that would not be a good idea.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Again, this is not like I would. Just clarifying. But separate files is still ok as well, thanks!